# Migrating application from SSCE to SSE

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have a large project based on SQLServer-CE 3.5.  Now I need to convert it to SQLServer.  My questions are:

1) If I just change the connection strings in aap.config, will it work?

2) What about the datasets which have been made with SQLServer-CE database.  Shall I need to change them too or app.config change will help there as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Yes, you will need to migrate the data and schema, of course

2: Do you mean typed dataet, then no, you must recreate. Maybe consider using LINQ to SQL or EF insead of DataSets.